# How to create dynamic reports with crystal reports - Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, database, crystal-reports

I want to create a crystal report application in Visual Stuio 2008, which will be able to create reports by the user. the user will choose the filed he wants and the report will view them.

I also want to know if there is an option to create "smart fileds" which wil calculate for example an input - date and will view the date+ 3 days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create reports on the fly, but it isn't trivial.  Take look at these : [Crystal Reports API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb944221%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your firsrt question, but the last is definitely possible using parameters and formula fields (or doing the logic upfront before passing the parameter to your report.)